# Views Content slide show- with 2 rows

Tags: views

Please help me.I am searching for a content slider in Drupal 7 .

I have created a view for displaying products.A block is created for this view.

My requirement:

I need a content slider with 2 columns and two rows.All the view items should be displayed in the slider.There will be four node contents in each slider.

eg:    row1   row1
       row2   row2

Please find the attached screen shot .I hope this may help more.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First : download the [view slideshow](http://drupal.org/project/views_slideshow) model ;
second : add the field you want
third :from the setting you can add controller and pager 
to display the item like this you have to use it in css to display it as for item